# How to tell from a CIL instruction whether a field is read or written to?

Tags: c#, mono, cil, mono.cecil

I am currently using Mono Cecil to extract data from C# projects. Now I need to check whether a field is read or written to in each method.

How can tell from the [CIL instruction](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20III.pdf) that a field is being read or written to?

Because I doubt there a library in Mono Cecil similar to [Assignment](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Assignment.html) in Eclipse's JDT that allows me to extract the left hand side and right hand side. If there is, then I can just work from there.

Comment: By the way, I would recomment to use this CLI spec from ECMA: http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf&ei=qxMzS_6SFpD-sQOA7JHBBA&sa=X&oi=nshc&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAoQzgQoAA&usg=AFQjCNHVmOmltbTSIZzP5GDNTq_FFJMKIg - rather than MS spec. The latter has some implementation detail, but lacks navigable table of contents, which is very inconvenient. ECMA spec is also single file for partitions I-III.

Comment: Actually I have the ECMA spec, but I thought I only need the partitions III. So I just search for an url with partition III as url to attach to this qn. You mean I need sth else from other partition besides III, which other partitions should I look into?

Comment: Partition III is CIL instruction set, but it heavily references partitions I and II (which define basic concepts, CLR type system, and so on). The link I gave earlier is for all 3 partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction for direct field stores is `stfld`, so you'll have to look out for that.

Note that fields can also be indirectly written to via pointers (both `*` and `&` kind), which is impossible to detect in the most general case (as pointer can come from the outside).

Comment: What do u mean by "as pointer can come from the outside"? Can u give an example, thx? I know a bit abt pointers, but not familiar with it.

Comment: consider C# code: `unsafe void Foo(int* p) { *p = 123; }`. This can be called as `Foo(&x.y)` (if `x` is a local `struct`, for example).

Comment: I found out that ldfld and stfld only works for getters and setters.
For other read and store (other than pointers), u hv to use ldsfld and stsfld I think. I tried out the eg u gave and got ldflda when the method is called.

Comment: It seems like ldfld and stfld are for non-static and ldsfld and stsfld are for static. I tried it with non-static fields and saw the difference. Thx for ur help.